# Angular material expansion panel navigation bar problem

Tags: angular, angular-material, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a side navigation bar for my angular project.  I want my navigation bar to support expandable items so I used expansion panel for this.  The problem is that when I expand the navigation item the header moves to the items above and overlaps them, and the content of expandable panel is on top of the data below.  Below I am attaching some of my code and screenshots of the problem.

Thank you

**HTML**

```
        <mat-expansion-panel-header class="expansion-header" [collapsedHeight]="'48px'" [expandedHeight]="'48px'">
          <mat-panel-title fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <mat-icon>{{menuitem.icon}}</mat-icon>
            <span>{{menuitem.name}}</span>
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-nav-list>
          <a class="expanded-nav-item" routerLinkActive="active-route" mat-list-item
            *ngFor="let submenuitem of menuitem.state" [routerLink]="submenuitem.state">
            <span>{{submenuitem.name}}</span>
          </a>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

**SCSS**

```
  mat-accordion {
width: 100% !important;
// height: 48px;
.expansion-panel {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background: $light-grey;

  .expansion-header {
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    span {
      color: $text-color;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    mat-icon {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }

  .expanded-nav-item {
    height: 48px;
  }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you can provide some stackblitz or code snippet it would be awesome, but anyway i will try help. My guess is that you dont have specified any positioning for your elements, so they dont recognize each other as relatives and wont be pushing each other if the height is changing.

Comment: thank you @JacekRatajewski for your response.  I will check if what you are saying is the problem.